# HTML CSS Responsive Div Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have some divs that display nicely when on a desktop or tablet:
[image]

However, when I shrink it down to a mobile view, they look pretty bad and don't re-orient appropriately:

[image]

I'd really like them to automatically adjust such that when they are on a tablet device they show 3 in a line and when a mobile device they show 2 in a row like this:

[image]

It seems like this is exactly what `col-xs-6` is for in bootstrap, but when I add that in, it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="surveys" class="surveys col-xs-12"><div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="title">
                <h4 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Surveys</h4>
                <h5 class="sub-title">The Best Way to Get Free Coins</h5>  
            </div>
            <div id="surveys-list" class="col-xs-12"><div>
    <div id="surveys-list-container"><div class="survey-item">
    <div id="2697033" class="item survey">
        <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
        <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box"><div>

    <p class="amount">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

        <span class="value">49</span>
        <span class="currency">reward points</span>
        <span class="hidden">+More</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
        <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box"><div class="loi">
    <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
    <span class="duration">10 min survey</span>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div><div class="survey-item">
    <div id="2697013" class="item survey">
        <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
        <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box"><div>

    <p class="amount">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

        <span class="value">85</span>
        <span class="currency">reward points</span>
        <span class="hidden">+More</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
        <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box"><div class="loi">
    <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
    <span class="duration">20 min survey</span>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div><div class="survey-item">
    <div id="2697207" class="item survey">
        <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
        <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box"><div>

    <p class="amount">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

        <span class="value">85</span>
        <span class="currency">reward points</span>
        <span class="hidden">+More</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
        <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box"><div class="loi">
    <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
    <span class="duration">18 min survey</span>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div><div class="survey-item">
    <div id="2697031" class="item survey">
        <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
        <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box"><div>

    <p class="amount">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

        <span class="value">85</span>
        <span class="currency">reward points</span>
        <span class="hidden">+More</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
        <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box"><div class="loi">
    <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
    <span class="duration">10 min survey</span>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div><div class="survey-item">
    <div id="2697999" class="item survey">
        <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
        <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box"><div>

    <p class="amount">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

        <span class="value">87</span>
        <span class="currency">reward points</span>
        <span class="hidden">+More</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
        <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box"><div class="loi">
    <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
    <span class="duration">18 min survey</span>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div><div class="survey-item">
    <div id="2697687" class="item survey">
        <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
        <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box"><div>

    <p class="amount">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

        <span class="value">85</span>
        <span class="currency">reward points</span>
        <span class="hidden">+More</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
        <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box"><div class="loi">
    <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
    <span class="duration">10 min survey</span>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#surveys h4 {
    font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#surveys h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#surveys .sub-title {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#surveys .survey-item {
    float: left;
    width: 19.2%;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0.8% 5px 0;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 6px 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: visible;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#surveys .survey-item {
    float: left;
    width: 19.2%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0.8% 5px 0;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 6px 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
}

#offers .note, #surveys .note {
    display: none;
    font-family: Montserrat-Bold, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.625em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -0.5em;
    line-height: 2;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    color: #139493;
    background-color: #a5e2e1;
    border-left-color: #a5e2e1;
    border-right-color: #a5e2e1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dddddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dddddd;
}

#surveys .reward-box {
    font-family: BebasNeue, Impact, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.875em;
    /*padding: 10.2px;*/
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #17b4b3;
}

#surveys .reward-box .amount {
    color: #f6fcfc;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0.0125em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}

#surveys .reward-box .value {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: sub;
    margin: 3%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

#surveys .reward-box .currency {
    color: #d1f0f0;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 50%;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Montserrat-Bold, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 2.8em;
    white-space: normal;
}

#surveys .loi-box {
    font-family: Montserrat-Bold, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-indent: -2em;
}

#surveys .loi-box .duration {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Montserrat-Bold, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-indent: -2em;
    color: #888888;
    line-height: 16.8px;
    letter-spacing: .01em;
}

#reward-box {
    padding: 0px;
}

#surveys .reward-box i {
    color: #4ac5c4;
    margin-right: -3px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 0.0125em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*margin-bottom: 1em;*/
}

#intro-description {
    width: 50% !important;
}

#surveys-list-container {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Any ideas how I can adjust it so they responsively shift?

Thanks!

EDIT - Adding the html code with the added additional `row` and `col-xs-6` and the resulting output:

```
<div id="surveys" class="surveys col-xs-12">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="title">
                    <h4 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Surveys</h4>
                </div>
                <div id="surveys-list" class="col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <div id="surveys-list-container row">
                            <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div id="2697033" class="item survey">
                                    <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
                                    <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box">
                                        <div>
                                            <p class="amount">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

                                                <span class="value">49</span>
                                                <span class="currency">reward points</span>
                                                <span class="hidden">+More</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box">
                                        <div class="loi">
                                            <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
                                            <span class="duration">10 min survey</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div id="2697013" class="item survey">
                                    <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
                                    <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box">
                                        <div>

                                            <p class="amount">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

                                                <span class="value">85</span>
                                                <span class="currency">reward points</span>
                                                <span class="hidden">+More</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box">
                                        <div class="loi">
                                            <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
                                            <span class="duration">20 min survey</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div id="2697033" class="item survey">
                                    <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
                                    <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box">
                                        <div>
                                            <p class="amount">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

                                                <span class="value">49</span>
                                                <span class="currency">reward points</span>
                                                <span class="hidden">+More</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box">
                                        <div class="loi">
                                            <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
                                            <span class="duration">10 min survey</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div id="2697013" class="item survey">
                                    <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
                                    <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box">
                                        <div>

                                            <p class="amount">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

                                                <span class="value">85</span>
                                                <span class="currency">reward points</span>
                                                <span class="hidden">+More</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box">
                                        <div class="loi">
                                            <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
                                            <span class="duration">20 min survey</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div id="2697033" class="item survey">
                                    <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
                                    <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box">
                                        <div>
                                            <p class="amount">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

                                                <span class="value">49</span>
                                                <span class="currency">reward points</span>
                                                <span class="hidden">+More</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box">
                                        <div class="loi">
                                            <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
                                            <span class="duration">10 min survey</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div id="2697013" class="item survey">
                                    <span class="note new">&nbsp;Opened&nbsp;</span>
                                    <div id="reward-box" class="reward-box">
                                        <div>

                                            <p class="amount">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

                                                <span class="value">85</span>
                                                <span class="currency">reward points</span>
                                                <span class="hidden">+More</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loi-box" class="loi-box">
                                        <div class="loi">
                                            <img src="http://d34x0w7b7efh78.cloudfront.net/pl/js/iFrameV4/images/customizable/Iframe_icon-survey-LOI.svgx?publisherId=8549&amp;style=8e0056f626fc736c93d0e68f08b14008" width="20" height="20">
                                            <span class="duration">20 min survey</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Laptop (all it seems to do is add padding to the outside of the divs):
[image]

Mobile (seems to just scrunch it up more):
[image]

EDIT - I think the problematic CSS lies in here, when I add it back in, it seems to break the functionality:

```
#surveys .survey-item {
    float: left;
    width: 19.2%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0.8% 5px 0;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 6px 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Where did you use `col-xs-6`? It looks like all the survey items are in 1 big col-xs-12 which is not making use of the Bootstrap grid. Each survey item should be inside a col.

Comment: I added my bootstrap example and the resulting output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things in the custom CSS that are causing a problem. Mostly relating to setting with width and margins of each item. Just let each item fill the `col-*`..

```
#surveys .survey-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 6px 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
}
```

I also cleaned up the HTML. There are a lot of nested levels. Just make sure `col` are always the *immediate* child of the `row.

http://www.codeply.com/go/dqgFudTPTU

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks man! I nearly got to the same answer myself. But the clean html is definitely a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your column classes on the `survey-item` elements.  5 columns on a "desktop" view is not possible with bootstraps 12 column layout unless you want white space (must be an even number).

Example:

```
<div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div id="2697033" class="item survey">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You would also add the `row` class to your `surveys-list-container` element.  Final result would look something like this:

```
<div id="surveys-list-container" class="row">
    <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="survey-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Wanted to mention the way bootstrap columns work.  Given all columns have the same class you take the last number in the class name and divide 12 by that number to get the number of columns.  In this case a `col-md-3` would be 12/3 which would be 4 columns.  To get 6 columns you would take 12/x = 6 which would be 2 making the class you would use `col-md-2`.

Edit:  After seeing your css on `survey-item` I would recommend you change it to the following.

```
#surveys .survey-item {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 6px 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #cccccc;
}
```

Bootstrap columns will do the floating and width for you.  Ideally `padding` and `margins` will be added to a child element within your `survey-item` element.

Comment: Yea, that's what I had tried previously as I thought it should work (at least that's how bootstrap has always worked for me previously), but the above output happens - I added the edits and resulting screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

It seems these two lines were throwing off the bootstrap inherent behavior:

```
#surveys .survey-item {
    width: 19.2%;
    margin: 5px 0.8% 5px 0;
}
```

Removing them reverted back to the traditional bootstrap responsive grid system behavior.